# How to manually insert a default ListItem when DropDownList is bound to a datasource control

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

When editing a Employee, the Type is a DDL that display the value from the database. The problem is that some employee don't have type. I'm getting exception for that. So, I believe that I need just to insert a ListItem with empty value and a default text.

I've tried first to add a ListItem and set **AppendDataBoundItems** to **true**

```
<asp:ListItem Text ="" Value ="" />
```

But it didn't work.

I've tried this inside a page load event handler, but no luck.

```
drpList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
```

I'm using an ObjectDataSource. Does it have any effect on why it's not working?

Thanks for helping

Comment: You may use just sqlquery: select name, isnull(type, 'DefaultValue') as type from employees;

Comment: can you post your code-behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for inserting the default record should work, but instead of doing it in the page load event do it in the ondatabound.  That should get desired results

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drpList"
  ondatabound="drpListDataBound"></asp:DropDownList>

protected void drpListDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    drpList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
}
```